# How many natural numbers are there such that $n^2+2n+29$ is a square of a natural number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I tried factoring the $n$s and using the properties of numbers that differ by 2 but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Hint: find $k$ such that the number is between $k^2$ and $(k+1)^2$ (this will only work only for large $n$).

Answer (score 4):

So
$$m^2=n^2+2n+29,$$
that is
$$m^2-(n+1)^2=28$$
or
$$(m+n+1)(m-n-1)=28.$$
That can't have too many integer solutions...

Answer (score 2):

Write $$(n+1)^2+28 = k^2$$ so $$(k-n-1)(k+n+1)=2^2\cdot 7$$
So we have $n+k+1 = {28\over a}$ and $k-n-1 =a\in\{1,2,4,7,14,28\}$.

So we have at most 6 solution.

Comment: $n$ is a natural number, so $\frac{28}{a}>a$, so $28>a^2$, so $a\le 5$, so $a\in\{1,2,4\}$. Now you need to check the $3$ cases.

Comment: True, thanks. ...

Answer (score 0):

Just to be perverse:

Difference between consequtive squares are odd numbers.

$n^2 + 2n + 29 = (n+1)^2 + 28$$ so $28$ must be the sum of consecutive odd numbers.

$28 = 13+15$.

$13 = 2*6+1$ so $n+1 = 6$.  $n = 5$.

......

I think the cutest way is:

$n^2 + 2n + 29 > n^2 + 2n + 1 = (n+1)^2$ so if this is a square it is a square of something larger than $n+1$.

Let $m = n+1$ and $n^2 + 2n + 29 = m^2 + 28 = (m+k)^2$ for some $k > 0$.

Then $m^2 + 28 = m^2 + 2mk + k^2$

So $2mk + k^2 = 28$.  So $k$ is even.

Let $k = 2s$

$4ms + 4s^2 = 28$

$ms+s^2=7$

$s(m+s) = 7$.  $7$ is prime and $m+2 > s$.

So $s = 1$ and $m+s = m + 1 = (n+1) + 1 = n+2 = 7$.

So $n = 5$.

==== several other ways below ====

$n^2 + 2n + 29 > n^2$ so if $n^2 + 2n + 29 = m^2$ then $m > n$ so let $m = n+k; k > 0$

Then $(n+k)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 29$

$n^2 + 2nk + k^2 = n^2 + 2n + 29$

so $2nk +k^2 = 2n + 29$.

Note $2nk \ge 2n$ so $k^2 \le 29$. So $k = 1,2,3,4,5$.

$2n(k-1) = 29 - k^2$ so $29-k^2$ is even so $k$ is odd.  Obviously $k\ne 1$.

$k=3: 4n = 29-9= 20; n= 5;$

$k=5: 8n = 29-25=4;n = \frac 12$.

So $n = 5$.

.... which would have been easier to solve if we had done:

$n^2 + 2n + 29 = n^2 + 2n + 1 + 28 = (n+1)^2 +28=k^2$ so $k > n+1$.

Let $m = n+1$ and $k = m+t; t > 0$ so

$m^2 + 28 = (m+t)^2 = m^2 + 2mt + t^2$

So $2mt + t^2 = 28$.  $t$ is even.  Let $t = 2s$

$4ms + 4s^2 = 4*7$

$ms + s^2 = 7$.

$s(m+s) = 7$.  $7$ is prime so $s = 1; m + s = 7$.  So $m = n+1 = 6$ so $n =5$.

.... or .....

$n^2 + 2n + 29 = k^2$

$(n+1)^2 + 28 = k^2$

Let $m = n+1$

$k^2 - m^2 = 28$

$(k -m)(k+m) = 28=1*28=2*14=4*7$

$k-m = \{1,2,4\}; k+m = \{28,14,7\}$

$(k+m) - (k - m) = 2m = \{27,12,3\}$

$m = n+1 = 6; n = 5$

... or ....

$n^2 + 2n + 29 = (n+1)^2 + 28; 28 \ne 0$ so $n^2 + 2n + 29 \ne (n+1)^2$

$=(n+2)^2 - 2n +25; 2n= 25$ has no natural solutions so $n^2 + 2n + 29 \ne (n+2)^2$

$= (n+3)^2 - 4n + 20; 4n=20$ has a solution of $n=5$ so $n^2 + 2n + 29 = (n+2)^2$ could be a solution if $n=5$ and $n+3=8$.

$=(n+4)^2 - 6n + 13; 6n = 13$ has no natural solutions so $n^2 + 2n + 29 \ne (n+4)^2$

$=(n+5)^2 - 8n +4; -8n+4 < 0$ so if $n^2 + 2n + 29 = k^2$ then $k < n+5$.

So $n = 5$ is only solution